# Install macports port on brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, macports

Can I install macports port like this https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=ftpsync on brew ?

Does brew have mechanism for that?

Comment: No you choose macports or brew not both. You can probably anually convert the macports tcl instrcuctions to brew's ruby ones.

Comment: ALso look at rsync for doing a syncronisation,